# android change image view

Tags: android, imageview, handler, delay, each

I'm using handler to change a imageview each "x" seconds. I accomplish this, but two images of five not show the time indicate.

From the method oncreate I call other method: showimages();

This is some of my code in the method showimages():

```
    ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    final File directory = contextWrapper.getDir("publi", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
      int i=random;
      public void run() {
        File myfile = new File(directory, "publi"+i+".jpg");
            Log.i("PUBLI", "I want to Show: "+myfile);
            if (myfile.exists()){
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myfile);
                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
                publi.setImageBitmap(b);
                Log.i("PUBLI", "SHOWN: "+myfile);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Loaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
          i++;
          if(i>datos.length)//medir array-1
          {
          i=0;    
          }
          Log.i("ads", "POSTDELAYED INTERVALO");
          handler.postDelayed(runnable, 4000);  //for interval...
      }
  };
 Log.i("ads", "POSTDELAYED initial delay: ");
  handler.postDelayed(runnable, 4000); //for initial delay..*/
```

}

When I execute this app in the emulator two images are shown 1 second and the other images are shown the seconds of the code.

Comment: May be, Android is loading Image3 and Time x Completed and It will try to load another Image4. Try x=10 sec and then see the resultss

Comment: I made it, but no it the cause. When show the last image in my storage return to the image0. The problem is show two images some mileseconds and the others show the seconds established. I had seen this appears when dalvik freed space. How I can fix it?

Comment: 10-06 10:29:42.847: D/dalvikvm(848): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 20% free 6734K/8320K, paused 45ms, total 46ms

Comment: I forgot that I have a AsyncTask in my activity. It´s posibble that this be the cause?

Comment: May be, I cant say anything, add that code also